# Writing a Predicate

Tags: prolog

I'm new to Prolog and I'm trying to write a predicate, `goodveggies(X,Y)` such that the code runs the following way:

```
?- goodveggies(broc,spinach).
true.
?- goodveggies(X,artichoke).
X = broc
```

What I've tried:

```
% Define the facts:
  goodveggies(broc,spinach).
  goodveggies(broc,artichoke).     

  % Now make the predicate.
   goodveggies(X,Y) :- goodveggies(X,Y).
```

My program runs fine, but the problem that I am having is that my program crashes when I type something like, `goodveggies(broc, tomato).` I don't understand how to filter out the results I don't want in order for the program to run properly.

Comment: `goodveggies(X,Y) :- goodveggies(X,Y).` is quite directly self-referencial. It says *`X` and `Y` are good veggies if `X` and `Y` are good veggies*. Infinite loop. What are you trying to say with this rule? And what does it mean semantically for `goodveggies` to have two arguments?

Comment: @lurker: I think he want to maintain a database of *good combinations* of veggies.

Comment: @lurker: or the OP is not familiar with the *minimal world assumption*.

Comment: @CommuSoft at the moment, I'm leaning toward your first theory. :)

Comment: @lurker: the "or" is not exclusive, we're talking prolog after all ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't understand why you define the predicate

```
goodveggies(X,Y) :- goodveggies(X,Y).
```

This doesn't make sense at all since goodveggies `(X,Y)` appears to be true if it is true. Furthermore say you want to query for `goodveggies(broc, tomato)`, it will have the following infinite executation (remarks added):

```
goodveggies(broc, tomato) :-
    goodveggies(broc, spinach); FAIL!
    goodveggies(broc,artichoke); FAIL!
    goodveggies(broc, tomato) :-
        goodveggies(broc, spinach); FAIL!
        goodveggies(broc,artichoke); FAIL!
        goodveggies(broc, tomato) :-
            goodveggies(broc, spinach); FAIL!
            goodveggies(broc,artichoke); FAIL!
            goodveggies(broc, tomato) :-
                ...
```

So you keep querying for the same fact.

You probably want to be able to swap the order in which the values appear, thus:

```
goodveggies(X,Y) :- goodveggies(Y,X).
```

Now this won't work either, since it will try:

```
goodveggies(broc,tomato) :-
       goodveggies(tomato,broc) :-
           goodveggies(broc,tomato) :-
               goodveggies(tomato,broc) :-
                   ...
```

You can however solve this by defining **two** predicates:

```
gv(broc,spinach).
gv(broc,artichoke).

goodveggies(X,Y) :-
    gv(X,Y).
goodveggies(X,Y) :-
    gv(Y,X).
```

The first predicate `gv/2`defines good combinations of veggies, the second `goodveggies/2` tries to query for both orders, if they both fail, the predicate ends.

What you have to understand in prolog is that everything that is **not specified as true** is false. That's what they call the *minimal world assumption*. So if you didn't specify `goodveggies(broc,tomato)` and it can't be derived by some predicate, the program will return false. In case you didn't want to have a variable order, listing the facts was fine:

```
goodveggies(broc,spinach).
goodveggies(broc,artichoke).
```

Comment: @JoffreyBaratheon: no, `grandma(X,Y) :- mom(X,Z), mom(Z,Y).` You need a person in between and you need to replace the "or" `;` by the and `,`. You can read this as: `X` is the grandmother of `Y`, given there exists a `Z` such that `X` is the mother of `Z` and `Z` is the mother of `Y`.